# How to use node server with Vue Vite bundler

Tags: vue.js, bundler, vite

Does someone know how to use Nodejs server instead of Vite own frontend dev server on the port 3000. I tried all command combinations like those below but with no success

```
vite
vite preview
vite preview --port:5000
```

Thanks

**UPDATE Feb 8-th 2022**
I have found a way. We have to add flag --watch to the vite build command, like: `vite build --watch`  That way Vite will bundle only changes to the front-end and store it in the `/dist` folder but it will watch outside server like Nodejs. That way we can develop both front and back end file simultaneously and see the result immediately. We have to launch server file separately and serve index.html from there. If we use Nodejs and Express on the server side we also have to point default directory to be `/dist` because Vite will put bundled files there, like `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));`. node will automatically serve `index.html` and other bundled files from this folder.

Comment: Why would you want that? Do you have problems with the built in dev server? Do you want to deploy the app?

Comment: @LielFridman I want to develop both front-end code and back-end server code simultaneously and see all code changes.

Answer (score 6):

Basically you will set the `middlewareMode` to `ssr` on the server options:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const { createServer: createViteServer } = require('vite')

async function createServer() {
  const app = express()

  // Create Vite server in middleware mode. This disables Vite's own HTML
  // serving logic and let the parent server take control.
  //
  // If you want to use Vite's own HTML serving logic (using Vite as
  // a development middleware), using 'html' instead.
  const vite = await createViteServer({
    server: { middlewareMode: 'ssr' }
  })
  // use vite's connect instance as middleware
  app.use(vite.middlewares)

  app.use('*', async (req, res) => {
    // serve index.html - we will tackle this next
  })

  app.listen(3000)
}

createServer()
```

**This is explained in the doc:** https://vitejs.dev/guide/ssr.html#setting-up-the-dev-server

### Update for Vite 2.x

For Vite 2.x set `server.middlewareMode` to `true` and `appType` to `custom`:

```js
  // ...
  const vite = await createViteServer({
    server: { middlewareMode: true },
    appType: 'custom'
  })
```

Comment: This was a super useful tip to me. Thanks!  However in Vite 2.x I got a warning message: 'Setting server.middlewareMode to 'ssr' is deprecated, set server.middlewareMode to `true` and appType to 'custom' instead'.  The fix is on the above referenced documentation page involving some updated arguments to the createViteServer call

Comment: I updated my comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See this example for another approach:
https://github.com/frameable/vite-vue-express-example

This way supports live updates with HMR in development, and runs in a single node process so you don't need to coordinate backend and dev server separately.